# blob to table mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, blob

I have a table with a field for text files. These files have multiple lines that I need to copy to a temporary table. I tried using Bulk Import like this:

```
Bulk Import MyTable From (Select File From FilesTable where Key = 1)
```

but no success (Incorrect sintax near "(").

Some people have sugested that I use the path of the file but that's not an option because the files are in a table.

Comment: use INSERT instead of BULK INSERT

Comment: You mean INSERT... SELECT...?

Comment: does the fields contain the names and path of the files or do you need to move data from table to table ?

Comment: Be specific please. Include TABLE definition, what's in the fields, and what you finally want done based on this information.

Comment: I have two tables: MyTable which is a temporary table that I'll use to store the data from the files and another table with 3 fields (Key, Date, File). The File field contains the data that I need to transfer to the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT this can be done with a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (
    File
)
SELECT
    [File]
FROM
    FilesTable
WHERE
    [Key]=1;
```